# Why wouldn't my reputation change for over a month?

Tags: support, reputation

For the last month or so my reputation points on Server Fault  has been 'stuck' at 812 and I can't figure out why it hasn't changed.   I visit the site very day and I perform about 10 minutes of activity on average.   Is my account locked or something?

Comment: You don't get rep for just turning up.

Comment: I see movement in your [rep graph](http://serverfault.com/users/9227?tab=reputationhistory). Not a lot, but some.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work

Comment: @random: on Meta, you pretty much do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably aren't getting any upvotes. Rep isn't automatic and magical.

Comment: Yeah, this isn't Eve Online or anything like that.

Comment: Still, it's highly unusual that the reputation count won't change *at all* over many weeks, so asking a quick question is perfectly valid.

Comment: *"Rep isn't automatic and magical."* Well, for *some* the former is false, but *everyone* knows the latter is false.  Rep is as magical as Unicorns!

Comment: I've been sitting at 3.8k or so for the past while on SU. Just can't find any interesting questions.

Comment: @Pekka: depends. I've been visiting for months, but due to my paying work I haven't contributed anything rep-worthy in a while.

Comment: @Anon yes, but I'd expect that one will get at least an upvote or downvote or two for older questions. But maybe that doesn't have to happen.

Answer (score 5):

Your reputation graph says you have gained rep during that time:

https://serverfault.com/users/9227?tab=reputationhistory#tab-top

You were somewhere around 780 in march.

Beyond what others have said (reputation only increases when other people upvote your questions and answers), a change was made to Questions in March - upvotes on questions were worth 10 reputation, but are now only worth 5 reputation.  You lost about 45 reputation when that change was made in March.

Comment: Even on a day to day basis it hasn't budged from 812 in a while.  Its wierd.  Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Now , 24+ hours later, after much activity, my points still remain at 812. Wierd.

Answer (score 3):

From looking at your history, it seems you just haven't been getting upvotes on your answers.

That could be due to a number of reasons, but by no means would I call it abnormal. Gaining rep is only a biproduct of the system, and isn't guaranteed.

If you focus on helping people, then the rep will come easily, and without effort.

Answer (score 2):

If you want rep badly, you need to do the following:

1. Ask a few well thought-out questions.
2. Answer a *lot* of questions with helpful answers.
3. Get your good answer in before anyone else.

The true secret to long-term rep gain is 1 and 2, but 3 can be a quick route to easy rep. Just answer quickly then expand on / improve the answer with edits.

Comment: Actually, 1 is much less "worth" since the vote value change on questions. It takes two votes on a question to have the reputation from one vote on an answer.

Comment: Don't forget excessive formatting. After you have written a quick one line answer to get the early upvotes, make sure subsequent edits have lots of headings and lists.

Comment: @Gnoupi: good point; I'd quite forgotten about the recalc. Still, good questions tend to accumulate rep over time as folks come in from google searching.

Answer (score 1):

If you add up your rep in the past month, you've had +65 from up votes, then -16 from down votes giving you a total of +49, so it's gone up ... just not by much.